# How can I install Spring web flow and Java servlet faces 2 in a Spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I want to develop a signup area for my web app. To do this I want to use Spring web flow for the flows management and JSF 2 for the user interface. How can I install Spring web flow and JSF in a Spring boot application?

Comment: Please take a step back and learn what the TLA 'JSF' means. Then search the internet and thirdly, modern jsf has its own flow so no need at all for spring webflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lots off tutorials on tbe internet. Why was 'tutorial' removed from the off-site resources?

Comment: Could you post some links of samples, because all online tutorials are old?

Comment: uhhh.... The standard jsf 2.3 tutorials have examples... Not old... please put a little effort in things. e.g. post the references to 'old' jsf flow tutorials... and state why you think 'old' is not ok in these cases.

Comment: Even Stackoverflow has hints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240734/advantages-of-using-jsf-faces-flow-instead-of-the-normal-navigation-system

Comment: You asked the same question 2 weeks ago...